# Looking for some advice on front end/backend user authentication

Tags: mongodb, authentication, express, ember.js, jwt

I'm running a mock expressjs server in the back, and ember (ember-simple-auth) on the front with the ember-simple-auth-token addon. I'm using JWT tokens. I'm trying to decide whats the best way to send my user information. Usually when the user submits their credentials I create a new token, store a copy of it in the database (I'm using mongodb), send it to the frontend and then use the token to fetch information user information. I have a /auth/token (which authenticates and sends the token, makes a copy and stores it in the database) & /current_user route which gets called on the initial login, which uses the token and fetches the user info.

Is it better to simply send the user info in the initial payload of the token over having a separate route? Should I be storing a copy in the database in order to do a comparison and retrieve user information?

Also what are the advantages of a token refresh?

Answer (score 0):

you are using Jwt-Auth for authentication.
-According to my knowledge after sending the user credentials u will respond with the token if credentials are correct otherwise send error.

-why are you saving the token in db ?.
  you will send token to client (stateless). If client requests for data then we need to check for token. if it validates then return proper response otherwise return token error.

-why you need token refresh?
 for security purpose. After response every time change the token.
 TTL your token will be valid for some time (say 60 mins). after that it will be invalid.

This is how JWT works.

Comment: Here's I have it setup. The user types in their username/password, I send them a token. Right now I have a route called /current_user, when the user gets his token it automatically calls /current_user, I use the token to verify which user info to send (since I have a copy of the token in the database, I compare the two, and send the "current users" information). Does it make more sense to simply send the user info in the initial payload? Should I decode the token instead of doing a comparison and send the data back to the front end?

Comment: I guess what I'm asking is how do you know what to send unless you have something to reference?

Comment: please go through this link. https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/wiki/Authentication         $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->toUser(); gives the user data . and then you can check the user type from that. No need to save token in db.(you are not doing it right). Actually token contains the details for user and time stamps etc.. (encoded). please check  in your case how to get data from token.

Comment: Thanks, I figured out the best way.